# Handling partial success of PFObject.saveAll()

Tags: parse-platform

I am creating a bunch of new objects in my Parse database using `PFObject.saveAllInBackground()`. Those are new objects that don't exist yet in the database.

Once they have been created, I need to keep track of their `objectId` in my local app database so I can update them later.

Using `saveAll()` is pretty much a requirement, as looping through 1000+ object and saving them individually is slow and it overwhelms the Parse backend.

The result of saveAll() is boolean: it tells me if the whole operation was successful or not.

However, when it returns a failure (with a `NSError` object telling me what went wrong), it is a possibility that some of those objects have successfully been created on the server.

In that case, I want to know which objects among my `saveAll()` batch were successfully created and retrieve their `objectId`, so I don't duplicate them when I try saving again.

So my question is: When `PFObject.saveAll()` fails, how do I know which objects have been successfully saved/created, if any?

Answer (score 0):

When you use saveAllInBackground (similar with saveInBackground) Parse will populate the objectId on the original object you wanted to save. See below:

```
PFObject *userObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:@[userObject] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"objectID %@", userObject.objectId); //ex: objectID C1w4kGNIfW
}];
```

Another alternative is to create your own id by using:

```
PFObject *userObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
NSString * uuidCustom = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
userObject[@"uuidCustom"] = uuidCustom;
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:@[userObject] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    //here make a Parse find using your custom UUIDs and see which one where saved. 
}];
```

Update:
Option 1 is not valid because Parse mention here:
https://parse.com/questions/saveallinbackground-and-deleteallinbackground-results-if-partial-fail

that *It returns YES if-and-only-if all objects were saved/deleted. If only some or none of the objects succeeded, then it will return NO, and some of the objects may have succeeded while others failed.*
So the saveAllInBackground doesn't do an atomic save.

Comment: Yes, but when I save a batch of objects and only a few of them are successfully created, their objectid is not set.

Comment: The custom uuid suggestion is interesting, but having to run a Parse query in order to know which objects were saved doesn't seem like a good thing to do, considering that this happens when the Parse save command fails - which could mean bad network, over quota, Parse timeout, etc... So the odds that the query would fail are high and I still wouldn't know which objects were successfully created.

Comment: Since you're saying that the Parse doesn't set the objectID even if the object was saved on Parse (which looks like a Parse bug and you should open a bug with Parse) you have to determine yourself if the object was saved. So you need to create your own unique ID and an UUID is a good solution. Regarding the timeout, you could create a local database with the records you asked Parse to insert and confirm which ones were actually saved before making another save. I hope this helps.

Comment: To be clear: Parse *does* set the `objectId` in the database for objects that have been successfully created. But the `PFObject.objectId` property is not set when `saveAll()` completes with an error.

Comment: Pascal Bourque did you figure out a way to handle this scenario?